# What are the different commands for `balance [detail]` in monero-wallet-cli

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, sub-address, multisig

Playing around with multisig subaddresses, I found we can create as many subaddresses as we want in any "account". I can have several accounts with several subaddresses for each account, that's pretty amazing and congratulations to the Monero Dev team by giving us these features.

When I want to search for a specific subaddress payment, what is the command, using the `monero-wallet-cli`, to check the amount received to that subaddress?

I tried with `balance_per_subaddress` or `balance_all` and neither worked. I ran the `help` command and it doesn't list any balance related commands other than `balance [detail]`.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `balance detail` will show your balance for each address in your current account.

The command `account` will show you the balance in each account.

The command `account switch N`, where `N` is the number/index of an account, will switch to that account. You can then use the command `balance detail` per above to show the balance of each address in that account.

The command `show_transfers` is what you use to identify specific transactions. For example, to see all incoming transactions to subaddress index 3 of the current account, run `show_transfers in index=3`.

There is detailed help on all the commands by running `help [command]`. E.g. `help show_transfers`.